Android connectedDebugAndroidTest fails after update Android Gradle Plugin
Everything workes ok on:
com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.3.2
After updating to
com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.4.0
I get the error:
Could not initialize class org.bouncycastle.operator.DefaultSignatureAlgorithmIdentifierFinder
or (for other module):
Execution failed for task ':feature_module:connectedDebugAndroidTest'. [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] > xmss_SHAKE128_512ph 
How to fix that?
